# String for inserting data with sub-select into database

Tags: c#

I'm new to C#. I would like to insert data with sub-select into my SQL Server database, I need help to write the string in C# for the following script in SQL Server.

I have two tables, `products` and `category` with foreign key between them and a temporary table `Mytemp`:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTemp(ID int)

INSERT INTO products (productName, price)
OUTPUT inserted.ID_ProductName
INTO MyTemp
VALUES ('Orange', '2')

INSERT INTO category (ID_productName, Category, Description)
VALUES
((SELECT ID FROM MyTemp), 'Fruits', 'DryFruits');

DROP TABLE MyTemp
```

Comment: Second statement is overly complicated. Do `INSERT INTO category (ID_productName, Category, Description)
SELECT ID, 'Fruits', 'DryFruits' FROM MyTemp`. Consider using a @table variable instead of an actual table (concurrency issues will arise)

Comment: _I need help to write the script in C#_ - "script" will depend on the framework/library you are using to connect and query database (EF Core, Dapper or just ADO.NET)?

Comment: Hi, I forgot to mention that there is foreign key between the two tables that´s why I used  a Temp table to get the ID from the first table insert to insert data into child table.

Comment: I need help to formulate this insert in C#  to insert with Parameters.insertWithValues

Comment: Temp table is not the correct way to get the foreign key. You want `scope_identity()`

Comment: Also, the schema design is not correct. `Category` should be it's own identity with it's own ID values, and then either include the category ID as a field in products, or if a product can have more than one category have a `product_categories` table the only includes the product and ID and category ID (no text).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a temp table for this, you can just do it this way:

```
INSERT INTO products (productName, price)
VALUES ('Orange', '2');

INSERT INTO category (ID_productName, Category, [Description]) 
VALUES (SCOPE_IDENTITY(), 'Fruits', 'DryFruits');
```

Comment: OP asking about _I need help to write the script in C#_, not sql

Comment: Notice that `@@IDENTITY` will not work for multiple products: _@@IDENTITY contains the **last identity value** that is generated by the statement_

Comment: @Fabio That's correct, in this example, we add only one item and therefore it works properly.

Comment: I would recommend to use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of anything else (like `@@IDENTITY`) to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Comment: OP's current code will work for multiple values, changing it to work with only single value is not an improvement ;)

Comment: @Fabio Why do you think his code will use multiple values? There is no point to add multiple values to a category with the same category and description. In his example, it looks like that his goal was to add one item. There is no need to add a table for one value.
If he will need a case for multiple values then he might use a temporary table with an output.

Comment: Hi, My goal is insert into two tables at the same time which have foreign key between them, so to insert to the child table I need the ID from the first insert that´s why I created a Temp table to output to Temp table the first inserted ID

Comment: @HaricheArquissandas That's exactly what my script does. Note that `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` function gets the last inserted ID. You can try to run it...

Comment: Thank you I will try.

Comment: If possible could you please formulate an insert in C# for the same

Comment: @HaricheArquissandas Sure. But I need more info about which technique you want and what exactly you want. There are lots of ways to do it in C#. What is your framework?

Comment: I created a widows form where I have Product Category Field (Textbox) and Subcategory to be inserted in Datagridview. 'm running DOT.Net Franmework 4.8